# returning new RedirectToRoute from canActivate() - "route not found", but URL properly generated

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In certain situations, I am attempting to redirect to another route on the same router that resolved to the current view/view-model by doing:

```
return new RedirectToRoute('participant-project-dashboard', {
  projectId: this.projects[0].id,
  projectUserId: this.projects[0].projectUserId,
});
```

The route is configured like so:

```
config.map([
  // ...
  {
    route: ['projects/:projectId/users/:projectUserId/dashboard'],
    name: 'participant-project-dashboard',
    moduleId: './project/dashboard/participant-project-dashboard',
    nav: false,
    title: 'AppName',
  },
  // ...
]);
```

What happens is the URL is being properly resolved; in the address bar of my browser I see:

`localhost:3001/#/projects/dd08adad-e67b-44cd-9f12-534f1b48b5b6/users/c6667081-5757-4cdc-8637-8935fa2fdb66/dashboard`

but in the console I get the following error:

`aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: /projects/dd08adad-e67b-44cd-9f12-534f1b48b5b6/users/c6667081-5757-4cdc-8637-8935fa2fdb66/dashboard(…)`

It's obviously finding my route, so why do I get "route not found"?

Comment: For now, I am going the route of returning a `new Redirect(\`participant/project/${projectId}/users/${userId}/dashboard\`)` and it works, but I'm not content with this solution.